# regex to fetch email and mobile numbers with space from a php string

Tags: php, regex

I have two regex to fetch email and mobile numbers. I have some strings in which Email or mobile number will be having some gap. I need to fetch those also.

```
preg_match_all("/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i", $text, $email);
preg_match_all("/(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[6789]\d{9}/", $text, $num);
```

I may have emails in this format in my string:

```
mail.email @provider.com
email- hfhh@hhd.com
```

And mobile numbers in :

```
+91-95544 xxxxx
+91 8765xxxxxx
9198765 546464
91 91212 92292 etc
```

How to get those emails and numbers

Comment: What is the actual question buddy? :)

Comment: *"I may have emails in this format:"* `mail.email @provider.com`, `email- hfhh@hhd.com` No you [can't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address). *"space and special characters "(),:;<>@[\] are allowed with restrictions (they are only allowed inside a quoted string ..."*

Comment: The string will be like that...I get it after some processing

Comment: Ah, misinterpreted, then

Comment: You never showed the entire `$text` of how it looked like.

Comment: a paragraph with emails and numbers in it in all these formats

Comment: should `email- hfhh@hhd.com` be matched as an email? if yes should the regex match `This is some random text with space email- hfhh@hhd.com` as a whole?

Comment: just the previous part only